# Merging dataframes and keeping columns in place?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frames:

DF1

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Key', 'Value'])
df1['Key'] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

DF2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Key', 'Value'])
df2['Key'] = ['A', 'C']
df2['Value'] = [1,7]
```

I would like to merge these two data frames such that the data from DF2 under the column 'Value' is filled in DF1, where the remaining letters 'B' and 'D' have zero.

I tried this:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer', on = 'Key')
```

However, this creates an additional column Value_x and Value_y which is not what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the shortest way to accomplish this is

```
df1[['Key']].merge(df2, on='Key', how='outer')
```

by not including `Value` from the left frame, you don't have 2 columns in the resulting data frame.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the `Value` column from `df1` and use your existing `merge`.

Or only use the `Key` column from `df1` when merging.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1['Key'],df2,how='outer', on = 'Key').fillna(value=0)

  Key  Value
0   A    1.0
1   B    0.0
2   C    7.0
3   D    0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is by concatenating the dataframes and then grouping the `Key` value like this:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).fillna(0).groupby('Key').sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Key  Value
0   A    1
1   B    0
2   C    7
3   D    0
```

This way is a little verbose but easier to read and extensible to more than 2 DFs.